# Pyinstaller can't find wcwidth "version.json" when running executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile a python script with sklearn, pandas, numpy and igraph, but the Pyinstaller executable doesn't run correctly because it can't find version.json in tmp folder.

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI106882\\wcwidth\\version.json'
[17248] Failed to execute script pyScript
```

Comment: Is `version.json` present there ?

Comment: I don't know, because I guess the tmp folder is deleted almost immediately after the error

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue, but adding the `version.json` manually via datas in my spec, however then I'm met with a `IsADirectoryError` when wcwidth attempts opening the file which is strange. Will post an answer if I can figure out the issue with that, but maybe that'll help get you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to include the `wcwidth` project directory in your data since it isn't considered a package or a module, its a data file.

In your spec file:

```
...

import wcwidth


a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=[],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[
                 (os.path.dirname(wcwidth.__file__), 'wcwidth')                 
                 ],
...
```

Note: Above I use `os.path.dirname(wcwidth.__file__)` to dynamically get the directory of `wcwidth`, but this can just be `.venv/lib/site_packages/wcwidth` or where-ever it is installed, this was just crucial for CI for me.

Or with `--add-data`:

```
pyinstaller --add-data "/path/to/site_packages/wcwidth;wcwidth"
```

Answer (score -1):

I hit this issue when creating a binary from a virtual environment. It seems installing ipython within the virtual environment is causing this.

Recreating a new virtual environment without ipython seems to overcome the issue.